# Prove this bijection $\tan x$

Tags: analysis

can you prove that $\tan x$ is a bijection from $\left]\dfrac\pi2 + n\pi ; \dfrac\pi2 + (n+1)\pi \right[$ to $\mathbb R$

$n$ is a natural number

we know that is it's a bijection from $\left]-\frac\pi2 ; \frac\pi2\right[$ to $\mathbb R$ ($\arctan x$) but $\left]\frac\pi2 + n\pi ; \frac\pi2 + (n+1)\pi \right[$ to $\mathbb R$ I can't prove.
Thank you

Comment: If you know that $\tan(x)$ is a bijection on $(-\pi / 2, \pi / 2)$, then you can use the fact that $\tan(x)$ is $\pi$-periodic to extend this result.

Comment: a detail answer plz , because I'm a beginner !

Answer (score 1):

Use $n\cdot\pi+\arctan(x)$ instead of $\arctan(x)$. It will give the same result that with $\left]-\pi/2;\pi/2\right[$ because $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$

Comment: Or use the fact that $tan(x)=tan(x-n\pi)$ and that $x\in] -\pi/2+ n \pi; \pi/2 + n \pi [ \rightarrow x-n. \pi \in ]-\pi/2;\pi/2[$ is also a bijection

Comment: a detail answer plz , because I'm a beginner !

Comment: sorry, i edit now

Comment: you know why it is good when $n=0$ ?

Comment: yes it's very easy

Comment: And that $\tan(x+n.\pi)=\tan(x)$ ?

Comment: yes because it's period is Pi ! I konw all that but how to give a good demonstration ( i mean an organiezd demonstration )

Comment: You explain that if you name the following functions :
$f: x\in\left]n.\pi-\pi/2;n.\pi+\pi/2\right[\rightarrow x-n.\pi\in\left]-\pi/2;\pi/2\right[$
$g: x\in \left]n.\pi-\pi/2;n.\pi+\pi/2\right[\rightarrow \tan(x)\in\mathbb R$
$h: \in \left]\pi/2;\pi/2\right[\rightarrow \tan(x)\in\mathbb R$,
then you have :$g=ho f$ and $h$ and $f$ are bijections.